# Making an yocto recipe for a package which uses meson with wrap

Tags: yocto, meson-build

I'm trying to study and setup an Yocto project and trying to add latest nvme-cli package to it.
I tried to find a recipe for that project but it seems like only the [recipe for 1.13](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-bsp/nvme-cli/nvme-cli_1.13.bb) exists.
And also build system is changed to meson after 2.0.
So, I created my own recipe like this.

```
SUMMARY = "NVMe management command line interface"
AUTHOR = "......"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli"
SECTION = "console/utils"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=8264535c0c4e9c6c335635c4026a8022"
DEPENDS = "util-linux"
PV .= "+git${SRCPV}"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli.git"
SRCREV = "0b2961e62f4138f991c3af6b5deea60d9900174e"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit meson bash-completion systemd
```

And I got this error during build.

```
Run-time dependency libnvme found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
Looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency libnvme

../git/meson.build:48:0: ERROR: Automatic wrap-based subproject downloading is disabled
```

After some investigating bbclasses and scripts, it was caused by nodownload for wrap-mode in meson.bbclass.

```
MESONOPTS = " --prefix ${prefix} \
              --buildtype ${MESON_BUILDTYPE} \
              --bindir ${@noprefix('bindir', d)} \
              --sbindir ${@noprefix('sbindir', d)} \
              --datadir ${@noprefix('datadir', d)} \
              --libdir ${@noprefix('libdir', d)} \
              --libexecdir ${@noprefix('libexecdir', d)} \
              --includedir ${@noprefix('includedir', d)} \
              --mandir ${@noprefix('mandir', d)} \
              --infodir ${@noprefix('infodir', d)} \
              --sysconfdir ${sysconfdir} \
              --localstatedir ${localstatedir} \
              --sharedstatedir ${sharedstatedir} \
              --wrap-mode nodownload \
              --native-file ${WORKDIR}/meson.native"
```

I want to know a right solution for this problem.
I believe that this isn't a rare problem and have a fixed solution.

Thank you for your interest and have a nice day!

Comment: which recipe does your libnvme come from? You DEPEND on it but meson (pkgconfig) does not seem to find it...

Comment: @JussiKukkonen Sorry. I uploaded fixed recipe not the original one which caused the problem. I tried with the recipe without libnvme and then got the error in the error description. And I also tried by adding libnvme at DEPENDS but is caused 'Nothing PROVIDES 'libnvme'' error as you expected.

Comment: Yeah, you'll likely have to make a recipe for libnvme first if one does not exist yet. Then the DEPENDS would likely just work.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen, I got it. It seems that making separated recipe for libnvme is the right solution. Thanks a lot!